# Rails4: disable edit, delete in dashboard/backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to show my work to clients. Clients could access the  front-end and back-end/dashboard but I do not want them to change anything as multiple clients may visit the site. Only user with role 'admin' can access the back-end (`user_type!='admin'`). It works fine but I cannot disable create,edit,update actions at backend. Not sure why ? I want to keep to the RESTful routes.

**Application controller**

```
def authorize_to_backend
 if (!current_user or current_user.user_type!='admin') 
 #login_dashboard is defined in router.rb 
 redirect_to login_dashboard_url, notice: "Please login" 
 end

end
```

i.e **Brands controller**

```
class BrandsController < ApplicationController
    layout :set_layout
    before_action :authorize_to_backend, only: [:create,:edit,:update]
def index 
...
end
...
..
end
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `before_action authorize_to_backend, only: [:create,:edit,:update]`? since you want to prevent access to those routes. `except` is telling the controller to run `authorize_to_backend` to all routes but `:create`, `:edit` and `:update`

Comment: I have changed it to only: [:create,:edit,:update], but I cannot disable those actions.

Comment: try `before_action :authorize_to_backend, only: [:create,:edit,:update]`. Note the `:` before the method name.

Comment: the reason for this is to prevent the method to execute at that point but in the request process middleware.

Comment: Thanks. `:` was removed when I edited my post. Updated my post, it does not work.

Comment: It is fixed now. Thanks nbermudezs.

Answer (score 0):

Added another checking in controller and it works :)

```
 before_action :authorize_to_backend,:redirect_user, only: [:create,:update,:destroy]

    private
    def redirect_user
       redirect_to request.referrer 
    end
```